# TLS termination of NLB

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, tls

**Objective:**

I would like to achieve the following with AWS and understand how to configure it:

**AWS Configuration:**

ACM certificate (associated with NLB listener).

NLB (in a public subnet, accepting TLS communication on port 5432, terminating encryption at the NLB, and forwarding TCP traffic on port 5432 to the db container).

db container (Postgres, in a private subnet, running on Fargate, and accepting TCP connections on port 5432).

**Goals:**

Encrypt communication from DB client tools and BI tools to the NLB.

Use TCP for communication between the NLB and the db container.

**Error Description:**

When attempting to connect using DBeaver (DB client tool), I encountered a "Read timed out" error.

Hostname: The ACM certificate's domain name.
Port: 5432.

**Checks Done:**

NLB logs indicate successful TLS connections.

There are no relevant logs in the db container.

Security Group (SG) settings appear to be configured correctly.

**Questions:**

Is the AWS configuration incorrect?

Is it possible to terminate encryption at the NLB?